# Adding 3rd level to CSS menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am using very old portal where the  is not defined in the begining of the html code, and also I managed to use a jquery/css horizontal drop menu, I need help adding third level to the menu here is my code

```
#jsddm {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#jsddm li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial
}
#jsddm li a {
    display: block;
    background: #324143;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    width: 70px;
    color: #EAFFED;
    white-space: nowrap
}
#jsddm li a:hover {
    background: #24313C
}
#jsddm li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid white
}
#jsddm li ul li {
    float: none;
    display: inline
}
#jsddm li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    background: #A9C251;
    color: #24313C
}
#jsddm li ul li a:hover {
    background: #8EA344
}



<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{   jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{   if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
    {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
</script>
```

and here is the menu

```
<ul id="jsddm">
   <li><a href="#">About us </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Mission </a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Mission Statment 1</a></li>
            </ul>
     </li>
      <li><a href="#"> vision </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">status </a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"> Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Office </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Support </a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see the 3rd level "Mession Statment 1" doesn't appear, and that's my problem, any suggestion ???

Comment: I would recommend using `$('#jsddm > li').hover(jsddm_open,jsddm_timer);` over binding both the mouseover and mouseout functions separately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is maybe due to these lines

```
$('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
$('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);
```

in which you set an event handler only to the direct `<li>` children of `#jsddm` element. But your third `<ul>` is not contained in a such `<li>`, so try to change the above lines in

```
$('#jsddm li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
$('#jsddm li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);
```

and

```
function jsddm_open() {   
    ...
    ddmenuitem = $(this).children('ul:first').css('visibility', 'visible');}
```